# Error with libcurl using cygwin64 on in windows 10(x64)

Tags: c++, curl, makefile

I have installed the cygwin64 on windows 10, also there are installed the g++ and the libraries of libCurl. When I run the code the g++ compiler throw me this error '#error Only Win32 target is supported!'.

How I solve this error?
Have I to install another version or library?

TestCurl.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <curl/curl.h>

static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  std::string readBuffer;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

MakeFile

```
CC=g++
MIN_GW = C:\cygwin64\usr\x86_64-w64-mingw32\sys-root\mingw\include

all: call.o

call.o: call.cpp
    $(CC) call.cpp -o call -I$(MIN_GW)
```

Error
[Errorlog](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iInTQTs7s89Ym59wr6Ez04RnJ_5cnMd9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Mingw and cygwin are different things. You are mixing a cygwin compiler with mingw includes.

Comment: You should probably uninstall Cygwin completely and just install separate mingw-w64 builds.

Comment: I added that parameter to the g++ but it generates the same error.